# How to set new X / Y coordinates when a triangle leaves the canvas window?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, random

In the moment canvas creates 15 triangles which moves with different velocity. When one of them leaves the canvas window:

```
if(p.x >= W){
p.x = -300;
//Set new y coordinates
}
```

After that it starts from the beginning so its a loop. The Problem is, that the triangle starts from the same y coordinates where it is set in the beginning. How do I can say that the triangle should have new y coordinates when it leaves the window?

```
    window.onload = function () {

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var H = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);

reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
               window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
               window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
               window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
               window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

var mp = 15; //max particles
var particles = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
    {
        particles.push({
            x: Math.floor(Math.random()*W), //x-coordinate
            y: Math.floor(Math.random()*H), //y-coordinate
            d: Math.floor(Math.random()*(mp - 1) + 1) //density
        })
        console.log("again");
    }



function animate() {

    reqAnimFrame(animate);
    for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
        {
            var p = particles[i];
            p.x += p.d;

            if(p.x >= W){
                p.x = -300;
                //Give the triangle new y coordinates
            }
            draw();
        }

}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,204,142,1";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++)
        {
            var p = particles[i];
            ctx.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p.x + 150, p.y + (-180));
            ctx.lineTo(p.x + 300, p.y);
        }
    ctx.fill();

}
    animate();
};//onload function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the y coordinate of a triangle once it leaves the window, all you need to do is reuse the code `p.x = -300;` and customize it for the y coordinate.

Example:

```
if(p.x >= W){
    p.x = -300;
    p.y = -300; //Or whatever you want it to be
}
```

Now, I assume you probably want a new *random* y coordinate. If you do, here replace the `p.y = -300;` by `p.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*H);`

Hope that helps!